# Заменить один div на другой с условием

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть один div вывода цены:

```
<div class="home-main-block_price">
  <p>цена</p>
  <span>
    <p id="calculated_price" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 34px;></p>
  </span>
  <p>с НДС</p>
  <button type="button">Заказать</button>
</div>
```

Цена считается из формы.
Если значение поля с `id="calculated_price"` будет равно 0 то вывести вместо него другой div:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">                    
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Позвоните нам!</p>
    </div>                      
  </div>                
</div>
```

Помогите. Очень нужно. Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: Может, по условию показывать один блок и скрывать другой?

Comment: в js, jquery не силен. не могли бы помочь.

Comment: id="calculated_price" будет равно 0 - вы имеете ввиду значение поля?

Comment: @qpeela да. оно подсчитывается в функции, и проставляется в это поле

Comment: @Viktor при нажатие кнопки нужно выводить модалку?

Comment: модалка должна закрывать первый див, когда в id="calculated_price" передается значение 0 без нажатия кнопки.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросу более 2 лет, он не имеет принятого решения. Единственный ответ без оценки и длинной цепочкой комментариев.

Answer (score 0):

При загрузке страницы проверяется значения поля с `id = calculated_price`, если `равно 0` то выводим второй `<div class="modal-dialog">` и прячем первый `<div class="home-main-block_price">`. Нужно вставить мой скрипт, так чтобы он запускался только после такого как посчитается и добавится значение в поле .

```css
.modal-dialog {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="home-main-block_price">
    <p>цена</p>
    <span>
      <p id="calculated_price" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 34px;">0</p>
    </span>
    <p>с НДС</p>
    <button type="button">Заказать</button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Позвоните нам!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>    
    var price = document.getElementById('calculated_price').innerHTML;
    var mainBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('home-main-block_price')[0];
    if (price == 0) {
      var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
      modal.classList += ' visible';
      mainBlock.classList += ' hidden';
    }  
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Что-то не выводится див модалки. Обработка цены проходит в контроллере. Допустим переменная `$tariff = 0;`. С помощью функции `<script>
            function calc(){
                $('#calculated_price').load('/calc/?'+$('#calc_form').serialize());
            }
        </script>` это дело обрабативается и передается.

Comment: @Viktor вы в свой код вставили мой? может вы модалке не дали `id="modal"`

Comment: сейчас блок "home-main-block_price" скрытый. а отображается блок "modal-dialog"

Comment: @Viktor а вам как надо?

Comment: мне нужно, чтоб изначально показывался див  _home-main-block_price_, потом, когда _id="calculated_price"_ получает значение цены например 10.00, див  _home-main-block_price_ скрывался, а поверх него выскакивал див _modal-dialog_ с сообщением. Спасибо.

Comment: @Viktor вы же написали что когда равен 0? он так и работает этот скрипт

Comment: @Viktor вы проверили мой пример? он правильно работает? Если правильно то мне сложно сказать почему ваш не работает код не видя его. Вы добавил в html код саму модалку?

Comment: все. спасибо. работает. а подскажите пожалуйста если вместо 0 ставлю те же 10, то выводит оба дива. как это можно исправить? еще раз спасибо большое.

Comment: @Viktor модалка должна быть скрыта по умолчанию - `.modal-dialog { display: none; }` должен быть в css и по умолчанию не будет выводиться

Comment: @Viktor ну css подключается в хэдере

Comment: прошу прощения. еще такой вопрос. дело в том, что при загрузке страницы, значение_<p id="calculated_price" >__</p>_ есть пустым. Оно заполняется при вводе значений веса динамически. Соответственно скрипт не может правильно сработать. Что можно сделать? Скрипт расположил после подсчета и добавления значения в поле. СПАСИБО!

Comment: Если статически ввести значение id="calculated_price, все работает отлично.